# Buffer-locally overriding minor-mode key bindings in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I want to use a minor mode which rebinds a major-mode key that I definitely want to keep. How can I rebind the key without deleting it from the minor-mode map globally? I know I can use `define-key` for that, but I would like to keep the binding for other buffers/major modes.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a bit cumbersome to do.  You can do something like:

```
(add-hook '<major-mode>-hook
  (lambda ()
    (let ((oldmap (cdr (assoc '<minor-mode> minor-mode-map-alist)))
          (newmap (make-sparse-keymap)))
      (set-keymap-parent newmap oldmap)
      (define-key newmap [<thekeyIwanttohide>] nil)
      (make-local-variable 'minor-mode-overriding-map-alist)
      (push `(<minor-mode> . ,newmap) minor-mode-overriding-map-alist))))
```

Comment: Great, that work! I'm surprised that this seemingly simple task is so cumbersome...

Comment: sebhofer: The whole intention of mode-specific key maps is that they *do* take effect everywhere that mode is active, so I wouldn't call the task of circumventing that behaviour "seemingly simple" at all. Given those circumstances, this solution looks quite elegant.

Comment: @phils Well from a bit naive point of view the task is: Overwrite a keybinding in a given buffer. Seems simple enough to me.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a function to handle all the cumbersome bits.

```
(defun local-set-minor-mode-key (mode key def)
  "Overrides a minor mode keybinding for the local
   buffer, by creating or altering keymaps stored in buffer-local
   `minor-mode-overriding-map-alist'."
  (let* ((oldmap (cdr (assoc mode minor-mode-map-alist)))
         (newmap (or (cdr (assoc mode minor-mode-overriding-map-alist))
                     (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
                       (set-keymap-parent map oldmap)
                       (push `(,mode . ,map) minor-mode-overriding-map-alist) 
                       map))))
    (define-key newmap key def)))
```

Thereafter you can do

```
(local-set-minor-mode-key '<minor-mode> (kbd "key-to-hide") nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, `company-mode` was overriding the `cider-repl-mode` bindings for `M-p` and `M-n` when the Company completions menu was showing. The keymap for the completions menu is `company-active-map`, but there's no minor mode corresponding to it (`company-mode` is for when the menu is **not** active), so I couldn't use any of the existing answers.

Here's what I came up with instead:

```
(add-hook 'cider-repl-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (make-local-variable 'company-active-map)
            (setq company-active-map (copy-tree company-active-map))
            (define-key company-active-map (kbd "M-p") nil)
            (define-key company-active-map (kbd "M-n") nil)))
```