# Locally override keybinding for emacs major mode

Tags: emacs, scope, key-bindings

What is the proper way to override a keybinding for a major mode so it only affects the buffer-local keymap?  I thought I could use `local-set-key` or `make-local-variable`, but my attempts there affect the keymaps globally (shown below).

Is it necessary to copy the map, as done below, or create a minor mode with a different keymap?  It would be nice to be able to make it a local variable if possible.

For example, say I want to have `original` bound to `C-c C-c` in the global `emacs-lisp-mode-map` but after calling `jump-to-other-buffer` I want `C-c C-c` to be bound to `local-version` only in that buffer.

```
(defun original ()
  (interactive)
  (message "original"))

(defun local-version ()
  (interactive)
  (message "local binding"))

;; open new buffer in emacs-lisp mode and set a local key
(defun jump-to-other-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*test1*")
    (emacs-lisp-mode)
    ;; These change bindings in all elisp buffers
    ;; (make-local-variable 'emacs-lisp-mode-map)
    ;; (define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'local-version)
    ;; (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") 'local-version)
    (let ((overriding-local-map (copy-keymap emacs-lisp-mode-map)))
      (define-key overriding-local-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'local-version)
      (use-local-map overriding-local-map))
    (pop-to-buffer (current-buffer))))

;; default binding in elisp buffers
(define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'original)
```

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/a/21493693 help? This looks close enough to being a duplicate of that.

Comment: @phils yea that's a good answer, thanks.  So, it doesn't need to copy the keymap, but only set the parent.

Comment: If you copy a keymap then future changes to the original would not be reflected in the copy; so directly using the original as a parent is a more robust approach.