# How to unset a keybinding in a map locally to a mode?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, elisp, key-bindings

I have set up a key binding for a function that modifies the behavior of Emacs `auto-complete`:

```lisp
;; ISSUE: when I type the whole candidate string and then press [SPC], 
;; Emacs will insert two spaces.
(define-key ac-menu-map (kbd "SPC")
  (defun ac-complete-with-space ()
    "Select the candidate and append a space. Save your time for typing space."
    (interactive)
    (ac-complete)
    ;; FIXME: this auto-inserts two spaces.
    (insert " ")
    ))
```

... and I want to disable this key binding in `ac-menu-map` **in** `org-mode` **only**.

I have tried the following:

```lisp
;; Avoid always selecting unwanted first candidate with auto-complete 
;; when writing in org-mode.
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            ;; (define-key ac-menu-map (kbd "SPC") nil)
            ;; (define-key ac-menu-map (kbd "SPC") 'self-insert-command)
            ;; (setq-local ac-menu-map (delq (kbd "SPC") ac-menu-map))
            ))
```

Unfortunately, this does not unset the key binding *locally* (i.e., only in `org-mode`). Instead, it removes the key binding from the `ac-menu-map` everywhere.

Comment: Keymaps are (by default) global variables. If you `(define-key ac-menu-map ...)` *anywhere* it affects that keymap *everywhere*. You can either do what juanleon suggested and bind the key (everywhere) to a function which checks the current major mode and then acts accordingly; or you could use org-mode-hook to make `ac-menu-map` buffer-local for org-mode buffers, and modify it that way.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Buffer-locally overriding minor-mode key bindings in Emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13102494/324105).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```lisp
(defun ac-complete-with-space ()
  "Select the candidate and append a space. save your time for typing space."
  (interactive)
  (ac-complete)
  (insert " ")
  )

;; NOTE: ac-completing-map is the parent map of ac-menu-map.
(define-key ac-completing-map (kbd "SPC") 'ac-complete-with-space)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key ac-menu-map (kbd "SPC") 'self-insert-command)))
```

Answer (score 5):

A different approach to solve your problem would be to check in `ac-complete-with-space` the mode.  If `org-mode`, then call `self-insert-command`, else follow your current logic.

Comment: I use code like this:

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (eval-after-load 'auto-complete
              (define-key ac-menu-map (kbd "SPC") 'self-insert-command))
            ))

But this does not work.