# Override (globally override key binding in emacs) temporarily

Tags: emacs, elisp, key-bindings

I use the method stated here : [globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs)

```
(defvar my-keys-minor-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map (kbd "C-i") 'some-function)
    map)
  "my-keys-minor-mode keymap.")

(define-minor-mode my-keys-minor-mode
  "A minor mode so that my key settings override annoying major modes."
  ;; Define-minor-mode will use `my-keys-minor-mode-map' for us.
  :init-value t
  :lighter " my-keys")

(defun my-keys-keep-on-top (&rest _)
  "Try to ensure that my keybindings always have priority."
  (unless (eq (caar minor-mode-map-alist) 'my-keys-minor-mode)
    (let ((mykeys (assq 'my-keys-minor-mode minor-mode-map-alist)))
      (assq-delete-all 'my-keys-minor-mode minor-mode-map-alist)
      (add-to-list 'minor-mode-map-alist mykeys))))
(add-hook 'after-load-functions #'my-keys-keep-on-top)

(my-keys-minor-mode 1)
```

How to I explicitly override this?
The methods in the link is not working to me.

**EDIT2 :**

Issue is not only applied to read only mode. The `eval-after-load` is not a good method since it makes change to `my-minor-mode-keymap` in long term.

I put another example here:

I use program mode for most of the time. Suppose I want to have `C-q` bind to syntax-check in program mode. However, I jot notes in text mode sometime. It makes no sense to have syntax check in text mode. So I decide to have `C-q` bind to spell-check.

Under normal circumstances, I would do this

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-q") 'syntax-check)
(define-key text-mode-map (kbd "C-q") 'spell-check)
```

How to have such effect if I define my-keys-minor-mode-map?
Assume I put this in my keymap:

```
(define-key 'my-keys-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-q") 'syntax-check)
```

`(define-key text-mode-map (kbd "C-q") 'spell-check)` doesn't work since my keymap always has precedence over other minor mode mapping.

Neither

```
(eval-after-load "text-mode"
  (define-key my-keys-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-q") 'spell-check))
```

nor

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-map (lambda () 
  (define-key my-keys-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-q") 'spell-check)))
```

do a good job because they change the my-keys-minor-mode-map in long term. That means when I switch back from text mode to program mode, I lose syntax check function.

**EDIT :**

For example,

```
(define-key my-keys-minor-mode-map (kbd "<return>") 'newline-and-indent)
```

this works 99% of time and is good to prevent any other minor modes or major modes to modify this.

However, the key map has problem in read only mode. So I need to have "super priority" function to remap this key. I want something like

```
(defun super-priority-map()
  (define-key super-my-keys-minor-mode-map (kbd "<return>") 'something-else))
(add-hook 'some-modes 'super-priority-map)
```

And more important, the super-priority-map should take off as long as that specified mode is left.

Comment: I am familiar with the linked question, and all of the code you have shown, but I have absolutely no idea what your question is. Please elaborate, in as much detail as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're talking about read-only functionality? You can't override that with a keymap. There's no "read-only" keymap capturing all keystrokes and issuing errors.

To override `read-only-mode`, just toggle off `read-only-mode`!

In code, set the `buffer-read-only` variable.

You can also let-bind the `inhibit-read-only` variable in code to ignore *all* read-only mechanisms (including properties on specific regions of text -- see levels 7 and 3 in the list below).

---

Read-only aside, it *is* entirely possible for other keymaps to have precedence over your minor mode map, but I'm inclined to say that for any rare conflicts with your minor mode keymap, you should directly modify the keymap which is conflicting with your own.

Your minor mode keymap can in fact be superseded by many others, but you probably don't *want* to be working at a higher level of priority in general.

I recommend reading [Mastering Key Bindings in Emacs](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs) which is a very readable explanation of how this stuff works, and from which I've nabbed the following keymap priority list:

1. `overriding-terminal-local-map` for terminal-specific key binds.
2. `overriding-local-map` for keys that should override all other local keymaps. Be VERY careful if you use this!
3. `Keymap` char property at point for keymaps that are local to the character point is at. This is used for stuff like fields in yasnippet and the customize dialog.
4. `emulation-mode-map-alists` for advanced multi-mode keymap management
5. `minor-mode-overriding-map-alist` for overriding the keymaps used by minor modes in major modes.
6. `minor-mode-map-alist` is exactly like the overriding version above, but the preferred means of specifying the keymaps for minor modes.
7. `Keymap` text property at point is like the one above for char properties but is for text properties only.
8. `current-local-map` for keymaps defined in the buffers’ current local map
9. `current-global-map` is the last place Emacs will look for key binds and it is for the global ones.

Note that your minor mode is working at level 6, and everything above that could take precedence.

A typical pattern to unbind a conflict would be:

```el
(eval-after-load "NAME-OF-LIBRARY"
  '(define-key NAME-OF-KEYMAP (kbd "KEY") nil)) ;; unbind KEY in KEYMAP implemented by LIBRARY
```

Most likely, you would also *add* a replacement (non-conflicting) binding for the original command.

Comment: Appreciate for your help. But the solution still not hit the spot. I make an update in the question in EDIT2.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you unbind keys from *your* mode's keymap. I was suggesting that you unbind the conflicting keys from the *other* keymap (so that they cannot clobber your own bindings). `eval-after-load` may be required when doing this because, if the library which defines that keymap is not loaded by default, the keymap variable will not exist until after the library has been loaded, so you need to defer the modification until then.

Answer (score 0):

[buffer-locally-overriding-minor-mode-key-bindings-in-emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102494/buffer-locally-overriding-minor-mode-key-bindings-in-emacs)

Combining everything togather

```
(defvar my-keys-minor-mode-map (make-keymap) "my-keys-minor-mode keymap.")

(define-minor-mode my-keys-minor-mode
  "A minor mode so that my key settings override annoying major modes."
  t " my-keys" 'my-keys-minor-mode-map)

(defadvice load (after give-my-keybindings-priority)
  "Try to ensure that my keybindings always have priority."
  (unless (eq (caar minor-mode-map-alist) 'my-keys-minor-mode)
    (let ((mykeys (assq 'my-keys-minor-mode minor-mode-map-alist)))
      (assq-delete-all 'my-keys-minor-mode minor-mode-map-alist)
          (add-to-list 'minor-mode-map-alist mykeys))))
    (ad-activate 'load)

(defun my-keys-minor-mode-override (key def)
  "Overrides a minor mode keybinding for the local
   buffer, by creating or altering keymaps stored in buffer-local
   `minor-mode-overriding-map-alist'."
    (let* ((oldmap (cdr (assoc 'my-keys-minor-mode minor-mode-map-alist)))
           (newmap (or (cdr (assoc 'my-keys-minor-mode minor-mode-overriding-map-alist))
                     (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
                       (set-keymap-parent map oldmap)
                       (push `(my-keys-minor-mode . ,map) minor-mode-overriding-map-alist) 
                       map))))
  ;; (make-local-variable 'minor-mode-overriding-map-alist)
  (define-key newmap key def)))

(my-keys-minor-mode 1)
```

What this can do is:

```
(define-key my-keys-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-i") 'backward-char)
```

to define a high precedence keybind over other minor mode.

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook (lambda ()
    (my-keys-minor-mode-override (kbd "C-i") 'forward-char)))
```

to override the high precedence keybind temporarily.

Sweet

Comment: That seems like a rather unpleasant alternative to simply using `minor-mode-overriding-map-alist` in the first place; but regardless it only gets you one level higher in the precedence list, so this does not remove the potential for conflicts.

Comment: Wait, are you *just* trying to implement custom mode-specific keymaps which take precedence over your custom `my-keys-minor-mode-map`? If so, why on earth did you use read-only mode as an example of the problem??

Comment: "are you just trying to implement custom mode-specific keymaps which take precedence over your own keymap" Yes.... Thanks very much for the infomation you provided. You guided me to the correct way to the solotion.